# Python/MySQL: Escaping strings used as parameters in raw database queries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using a connection/cursor to migrate data from an old database/schema into a new one built with Django models. I encounter a problem with names that have an apostrophe

to simplify

```
business = "Tom's Diner"
cursor.execute("select * from businesses where name = '" + business + "'")
```

This would obviously fail as I'm forcing a single quote which causes an SQL syntax problem. It would work if I did this:

```
business = "Tom''s Diner"
```

But as this is an automated process that deals with migrating millions of rows. I am looking for a way to escape my string **before** applying it to the direct MySQL query.

My question: is that something I have to do manually, or is there some function in Django/Python that escapes strings, and may handle cases I haven't even thought of yet, like double quotes in the string, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```py
cursor.execute("select * from businesses where name = %s ", (business ,))
```

make sure the second parameter is a tuple:  `(business,) not (business)`

Comment: hmm interesting. will try.

Comment: +1, the equivalent module for Postgres (psycopg) stresses in it's documentation that you should use this method rather than constructing your own query strings.